# Check xsi:null: true in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am fetching a custom object from a crm framework which contains data related to an entity for e.g. company
and then i access that data field wise as "crmRecord.comp_delivery" , "crmRecord.comp_name" etc.
but there are some value which are as belows:
[image]

I want to null check them and access their values if not null,
how to check for null/blank of such values
 I have tried doing

```
if(!crmRecord.comp_delivery)
```

as well as

```
crmRecord.comp_delivery.value
```

Neither works. How can I check if it's null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got some hint from @OmerAkgun's answer

How i tackled it (may not be the best solution!)

```
    if(typeof(crmRecord.comp_delivery) == 'string') {    
//      access value of crmRecord.comp_delivery

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do null check i think

```
if(typeof(crmRecord.comp_delivery) !== 'undefined') {
    //obj - prop not null or undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try With Different Logic**. You can use bellow code for check all four(4) condition for validation like not null, not blank, not undefined and not zero only use this code (!(!(variable))) in javascript and jquery. Try below logic according to your requirements.

```
 function myFunction() {
    var data;  //The Values can be like as null, blank, undefined, zero you can test

    if(!(!(data)))
    {
        alert("data "+data);
    } 
    else 
    {
        alert("data is "+data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But your code seems ok to check null

```
if(!(crmRecord.comp_delivery))
```

but i am not sure about your object element, did you print your object in console to see what's inside of object